# Command to set text color for current notebook

Tags: notebooks, customization, style

I'm looking for a command to insert at the start of my notebook that would change the text color for all text cells (style "Text") to have the color magenta. Maybe something that starts with

```
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ?]
```

but I couldn't figure out what the "?" should be. I didn't want to change the default stylesheet or create a custom stylesheet. I just want a notebook with a different text color for text comments, which I can to someone else, and it will still look the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit style elements using [`StyleDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleDefinitions.html):

```
SetOptions[SelectedNotebook[], 
 StyleDefinitions -> 
  Notebook[{Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]], 
            Cell[StyleData["Text"], FontColor -> Red]}]]
```

This command comes from examining the current value of [`StyleDefinitions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StyleDefinitions.html) option for a new notebook:

```
Options[SelectedNotebook[], StyleDefinitions]
```

Accordingly, you can modify what is in there by adding your own elements, using the same format as in style sheets.